# How to correct my php number_format error?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the error below with my array code. How can I fix this error to display the results?

**Error:**

`Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string`

**My code:**

```
$account['checking'] = 775.57;
$account['savings'] = 2275.31;
$account['moneyMarket'] = 4554.43;

print("<table>");
print("<tr><td>CHECKING BALANCE:  </td><td>$".number_format(checking, 2)." </td></tr>");     
print("<tr><td>SAVINGS BALANCE:   </td><td>$".number_format(savings, 2)."</td></tr>");
print("<tr><td>MONEY MKT BALANCE: </td><td>$".number_format(moneyMarket, 2)."</td></tr>");
print("</table>");
```

Comment: is that a typo? because the function your feeding into it is not proper, should be `number_format($account['checking']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $ to access variables...

```
number_format($account['checking'], 2)
```

otherwise you are checking for constants that may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you have:

```
print("<tr><td>CHECKING BALANCE:  </td><td>$".number_format($account['checking'], 2)." </td></tr>");     
print("<tr><td>SAVINGS BALANCE:   </td><td>$".number_format($account['savings'], 2)."</td></tr>");
print("<tr><td>MONEY MKT BALANCE: </td><td>$".number_format($account['moneyMarket'], 2)."</td></tr>");
```

instead of:

```
print("<tr><td>CHECKING BALANCE:  </td><td>$".number_format(checking, 2)." </td></tr>");     
print("<tr><td>SAVINGS BALANCE:   </td><td>$".number_format(savings, 2)."</td></tr>");
print("<tr><td>MONEY MKT BALANCE: </td><td>$".number_format(moneyMarket, 2)."</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing your array properly. `number_format(checking, 2)` should be `number_format($account['checking'], 2)`